# Run-time error: Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart - VBA - SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm running some code in Excel VBA which queries a database then brings the data into Excel for formatting.

It worked fine the last time I ran it (that old chestnut) but today I've come to run the monthly report and it is throwing up a datepart error as

> Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart

Here is the code:

```
    StrQuery = "SELECT dbo_MANUFACTURER.COMPANY_NAME AS BRAND, dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, dbo_AGENTS.SHORT_DESC AS AGENT, dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SHORT_DESC AS [STOCK TYPE], Replace(Replace(dbo_COMPANY.CURRENCY_ID,'110','EURO'),'1','GBP') AS [CURRENCY]," & _
    "Sum(([Unit_Net]*[QTY_SOLD])-[DELIVERY_TOTAL]) AS [NET TOTAL], dbo_SORDER.DATE_CREATED, dbo_SORDER.SORDER_CODE FROM (((((dbo_COMPANY INNER JOIN dbo_SORDER ON dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_ID = dbo_SORDER.COMPANY_ID) INNER JOIN " & _
    "dbo_SORDER_ITEM ON dbo_SORDER.SORDER_ID = dbo_SORDER_ITEM.SORDER_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_STOCK ON dbo_SORDER_ITEM.STOCK_ID = dbo_STOCK.STOCK_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE ON dbo_STOCK.SSTYPE_ID = dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SSTYPE_ID) INNER JOIN " & _
    "dbo_AGENTS ON dbo_COMPANY.AGENT_ID = dbo_AGENTS.AGENT_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_MANUFACTURER ON dbo_STOCK.MANUF_ID = dbo_MANUFACTURER.MANUF_ID GROUP BY dbo_MANUFACTURER.COMPANY_NAME, dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, dbo_AGENTS.SHORT_DESC, " & _
    "dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SHORT_DESC, dbo_SORDER.DATE_CREATED, dbo_SORDER.SORDER_CODE, dbo_COMPANY.CURRENCY_ID, dbo_STOCK.MANUF_ID HAVING (((dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SHORT_DESC) <> " & "'EMBROIDERY'" & ") And ((Year([DATE_CREATED]) * 12 + " & _
    "DatePart(" & "'m'" & ", [DATE_CREATED])) = Year(Date) * 12 + DatePart(" & "'m'" & ", Date) - 1)) ORDER BY dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, dbo_SORDER.DATE_CREATED;"
```

Apologies for the mass of text on long lines.
As mentioned the code throws up the error: Invalid parameter 1 specified for date part.  I've tried converting the dates as someone mentioned on a forum post but that hasn't been successful.

If someone has any ideas that would be amazing!

EDIT:

Removing the quotes around the **m** in datepart does not work in Access.  It pops up asking for a value for **m**
The SQL query I have works fine in Access, I have added it below:

```
SELECT 

 dbo_MANUFACTURER.COMPANY_NAME AS BRAND, dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME,
 dbo_AGENTS.SHORT_DESC AS AGENT, dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SHORT_DESC AS [STOCK TYPE], Replace(Replace(dbo_COMPANY.CURRENCY_ID,'110','EURO'),'1','GBP') AS [CURRENCY], Sum(([Unit_Net]*[QTY_SOLD])-[DELIVERY_TOTAL]) AS [NET TOTAL], dbo_SORDER.DATE_CREATED, dbo_SORDER.SORDER_CODE

FROM 

 (((((dbo_COMPANY INNER JOIN dbo_SORDER ON dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_ID = dbo_SORDER.COMPANY_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_SORDER_ITEM ON dbo_SORDER.SORDER_ID = dbo_SORDER_ITEM.SORDER_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_STOCK ON dbo_SORDER_ITEM.STOCK_ID = dbo_STOCK.STOCK_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE ON dbo_STOCK.SSTYPE_ID = dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SSTYPE_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_AGENTS ON dbo_COMPANY.AGENT_ID = dbo_AGENTS.AGENT_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_MANUFACTURER ON dbo_STOCK.MANUF_ID = dbo_MANUFACTURER.MANUF_ID

GROUP BY 

 dbo_MANUFACTURER.COMPANY_NAME, dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, dbo_AGENTS.SHORT_DESC, dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SHORT_DESC, dbo_SORDER.DATE_CREATED, dbo_SORDER.SORDER_CODE, dbo_COMPANY.CURRENCY_ID, dbo_STOCK.MANUF_ID

HAVING 

 (((dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SHORT_DESC)<>"EMBROIDERY") AND ((Year([DATE_CREATED])*12+DatePart(m,[DATE_CREATED]))=Year(Date())*12+DatePart(m,Date())-1))

ORDER BY dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, dbo_SORDER.DATE_CREATED;
```

Comment: Post the full error..

Comment: You have `DatePart(" & "'m'" & ", [DATE_CREATED]))`, which will give you `DatePart('m', [DATE_CREATED])`. Based on the error message, I am guessing that you are using SQL Server, and in SQL Server `'m'` is not a valid argument for `DATEPART`, you either want `DATEPART(MONTH, [DATE_CREATED])` (My preference as it is by far the most clear), or `DATEPART(M, [DATE_CREATED])` or `DATEPART(MM, [DATE_CREATED])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, you are confusing SQL dialects which use the same named function `DatePart` but with different arguments. Depending on architecture layer of your Excel app, you need to adjust the `DatePart` function according to the SQL dialect used either: ACE/Jet SQL or SQL Server TSQL.

- **Excel -> Access -> SQL Server** *(linked tables)*

  If Excel connects to Access database and this Access database uses
  SQL Server linked tables (Access objects), then you must adhere to ACE/Jet SQL
  dialect which requires the first argument of
  [DatePart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DatePart-Function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa)
  to be a string literal enclosed in double or single
  quotes as @Arulkumar shows in answer:

  ```
  DatePart('m', [DATE_CREATED])
  ```
- **Excel -> SQL Server** *(ADO)*

  If Excel connects directly to SQL Server via ADO connection in VBA
  then you must adhere to SQL Server TSQL dialect which requires the first argument of [DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to be a named value not string literal as @GarethD
  describes in comment:

  ```
  DatePart(MONTH, [DATE_CREATED])
  DatePart(MM, [DATE_CREATED])
  DatePart(M, [DATE_CREATED])
  ```
- **Excel -> Access -> SQL Server** *(pass-thru)*

  If Excel connects to Access database calling an Access pass-through query (not linked tables) and this pass-through query (scripted and saved in Access database) connects to SQL Server via ODBC/OLEDB then you must adhere to SQL Server TSQL dialect as described above.

From the nomenclature of your tables, I believe you are connecting to Access with MSSQL linked tables as SQL Server's object qualifiers maintain schema plus table plus field separated by periods:

```
dbo.COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME
```

When linked to Access, multiple periods in table names are not allowed so by default are replaced with underscore:

```
dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME
```

The invalid object error means either the Access linked table does not exist in Access database or the table does not exist in connected SQL Server database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I have tried your suggestions as per the Excel > Access Linked Tables > SQL database which is how this is set up. If I change the datepart and replace the dbo_ with dbo. ,excel/vba now gives no errors but the recordset returns no data and no error.  If I output the StrQuery string into a cell then copy into Access it tells me there is a join error and highlights the first dbo.  I just don't understand this as it worked fine when I ran it a few weeks ago, no errors and brought in the data fine.

Comment: So in Excel you are making an ODBC connection to MS Access? If so, why are you re-naming the tables? As mentioned, Access does not allow periods in table name and so replaces it with underscore when linked tables are crated. Please post full Excel VBA code to see connection. A small change in connection string from an Access to SQL Server source could be the reason for these new errors.

Answer (score 2):

Simply try with the below query

```
SELECT DATEPART('m', GETDATE())
```

returns the

> Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart.

[`MSAccess DatePart`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DatePart-Function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa), requires double quotes around the setting. So try with double quotes instead of single quote will solve your problem.

---

So your working query will be:

```
SELECT dbo_MANUFACTURER.COMPANY_NAME AS BRAND, 
      dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, 
      dbo_AGENTS.SHORT_DESC AS AGENT, 
      dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SHORT_DESC AS [STOCK TYPE], 
      Replace(Replace(dbo_COMPANY.CURRENCY_ID,'110','EURO'),'1','GBP') AS [CURRENCY],
      Sum(([Unit_Net]*[QTY_SOLD])-[DELIVERY_TOTAL]) AS [NET TOTAL], 
      dbo_SORDER.DATE_CREATED, 
      dbo_SORDER.SORDER_CODE

FROM (((((
dbo_COMPANY 
INNER JOIN dbo_SORDER ON dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_ID = dbo_SORDER.COMPANY_ID) 
INNER JOIN dbo_SORDER_ITEM ON dbo_SORDER.SORDER_ID = dbo_SORDER_ITEM.SORDER_ID) 
INNER JOIN dbo_STOCK ON dbo_SORDER_ITEM.STOCK_ID = dbo_STOCK.STOCK_ID) 
INNER JOIN dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE ON dbo_STOCK.SSTYPE_ID = dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SSTYPE_ID) 
INNER JOIN dbo_AGENTS ON dbo_COMPANY.AGENT_ID = dbo_AGENTS.AGENT_ID) 
INNER JOIN dbo_MANUFACTURER ON dbo_STOCK.MANUF_ID = dbo_MANUFACTURER.MANUF_ID 

GROUP BY dbo_MANUFACTURER.COMPANY_NAME, 
         dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, 
         dbo_AGENTS.SHORT_DESC, 
         dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SHORT_DESC, 
         dbo_SORDER.DATE_CREATED, 
         dbo_SORDER.SORDER_CODE, 
         dbo_COMPANY.CURRENCY_ID, 
         dbo_STOCK.MANUF_ID 

HAVING (((dbo_STOCK_SUB_TYPE.SHORT_DESC) <> 'EMBROIDERY') 
        And ((Year([DATE_CREATED]) * 12 
              + DatePart("m", [DATE_CREATED])) = Year(Date) * 12 
              + DatePart("m", Date) - 1)) 

ORDER BY dbo_COMPANY.COMPANY_NAME, 
         dbo_SORDER.DATE_CREATED;
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, this is confusing as the sql statement works fine in Access.

Comment: It is now displaying another error: INVALID OBJECT NAME DBO_COMPANY.  Again this is strange as the SQL statement I edited worked fine in Access.

Comment: Hi, sorry this does not work if I copy into Access.  It comes up with Enter Parameter Value for m.  However if I re-add the quotes the query works as expected.

Comment: @MHarkess: [MSAccess DatePart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DatePart-Function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa), requires double quotes around the setting. So try with double quote instead of single quote

Comment: Hi, thanks still getting the invalid object name dbo_COMPANY though.